# Textmate find and replace with encoding

Tags: macos, mac, encoding, textmate

I have to update a website with a lot of files. I am using Textmate's `Find in project` to replace text with a massive regular expression.

The problem is: the files are saved on a windows machine in ISO-8859-1 (Windows). Textmate likes to look at files as MacRoman or UTF-8. So, special characters such as curly quotes get replaced by bits of evil.

When I use `Reopen file with encoding` it reads the file fine. But when I apply a change using `Find in project` and then issue `Save all files` all the files get saved with the wrong encoding, leading to a lot of bad characters.

Has anyone any idea how to prevent this and make sure all the files are read and saved with the right encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Textmate can't do this so you might want to do command line replacements using [Sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html),
or look for an alternative editor that does handle encoding properly.

Comment: TextMate preferences does have an option to change the default encoding. I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: @ghoppe: me neither, but it seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the TextMate preferences under the Advanced tab? There is a popup for `File Encoding:` where you can choose the default encoding. ISO-8859-1 is available.

Underneath the popup there's a checkbox that says `Use for existing files as well` — have you checked that box?

Comment: Yes I have. Setting that to the correct encoding does indeed work well when opening a file. But this is not respected when modifying files without opening them, as 'Save all files' does.

Comment: @avdgaag See my edit. Is that checkbox selected as well?

Comment: yes it is.